# How can I use a json member object in dojo widget

Tags: json, dojo, widget

I am iterating a json whose format is like this

```
request("js/my/data/sample.json", {
    handleAs: "json"
}).then(function (jsonResults) {
    arrayUtil.forEach(jsonResults.LinksMap, function (List) {
        arrayUtil.forEach(List.LinksMap.entry, function (Ientry) {
            var widget = new support(Ientry.Link).placeAt(authorContainer);
        });
    });
});
```

The Widget HTML template looks like

```
      <div><span  title="${title}">${title}</span></div> <br />
 <div><span title="${description}">${description}</span></div> <br />
 <a class="info" title="${title}" href="${url}">${title}</a><br />
```

I would like to use the object linkType provided in json to use a different class in the html template of the widget so if it linkType is "information" then use

```
     <a class="info" title="${title}" href="${url}">${title}</a><br />
```

If it is news then use

```
          <a class="news" title="${title}" href="${url}">${title}</a><br />
```

Comment: Pass the entire `entry` to your widget and not just `Link`. Then the widget can add/remove CSS classes itself based on `linkType`.

Comment: @PaulGrime when I pass the entire entry it does not work as I have the html template use the Link object and its properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of this modified template:

```
<div><span  title="${Link.title}">${Link.title}</span></div> <br />
<div><span title="${Link.description}">${Link.description}</span></div> <br />
<a class="${className}" title="${Link.title}" href="${Link.url}">${Link.title}</a><br />
```

and this modified code should do the trick:

```
request("js/my/data/sample.json", {
handleAs: "json"}).then(function(jsonResults){  arrayUtil.forEach(jsonResults.LinksMap, function(List){arrayUtil.forEach(List.LinksMap.entry, function(Ientry){

  if('information' === Ientry.linkType) Ientry.className = 'info';
  else if('news link' === Ientry.linkType) Ientry.className = 'news';
  var widget = new support(Ientry).placeAt(authorContainer);

});});});
```

---

But a much better idea would be implementing a `postCreate` method in your widget that would be able to modify widget in any way you like, after it gets constructed and just before it gets displayed.

Please refer to [this guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/recipes/custom_widget/) and search for *postCreate* there.

Comment: that worked. I should use those in postcreate. I will do that. Thanks to both.

Comment: For some reason it also adds the class to the main div <div class="info" id="dijit__TemplatedMixin_2" widgetid="dijit__TemplatedMixin_2"> How can I override it?

Comment: I renamed it to something not including a class in its name and it works.

Comment: Oleg Mikheev How do I use your code on PostCreate. Do you have a sample